# Erasing portions of a shape in photoshop and adding text to the erased area

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create a rectangle that has openings at the top and bottom of it using photoshop. Like such (I created this using microsoft word just to have a template) . The issue I'm having is that I am unsure as to how I can do this using photoshop. I tried entering a filled white square in the area that I wanted blank but this restricted me from adding the text. Any idea on how I can achieve this using photoshop? I want to use this for my website header but the image from word comes up in poor quality.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to spend some time playing around with the [Layers panel](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-basics.html). While the method you've used isn't the best it should absolutely work, you just need to put your text on a higher layer than the white square you used to remove the black.

Nice choice of font for the Marissa XO as well!

Comment: Ahhh! Gotcha! I'll give the a try! SN: I love that font as well, too bad it's only a Microsoft font! Any tips on how I can get that over in Photoshop? Or is that not possible? I absolutely loved the logo I've created in Word but I'm finding that I am having to modify it in a lot (in terms of the fonts) to get it in Photoshop for better quality.

Comment: @MPurnell I don't know what you mean. Isn't that Engravers MT? It works just fine in Photoshop.

Comment: It sure is, however I'm not seeing that as a font option on Photoshop...

Comment: @MPurnell not sure, I don't remember having to do anything for it to work but I've had it for years so might just not be remembering. Perhaps make a new question and someone else might know. There are alternatives on Google Font you can download for free, but I definitely have Engravers MT in Photoshop - http://imgur.com/l4qmdAZ

Comment: You have literally just made my day! I was able to download the font and  use it in Photoshop AND apply the info you gave about layers. It worked like a charm! Thanks so much

Comment: You might want to mark Ryan's response as the answer to your question. That will make it easier for other users to find it in the future.